# why is vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector full of monster objects which are initialized onto a 10X10 map which works. I am now playing with some code to prevent monsters being spawned on the same map co-ordinate. when i run the code it cuts and brings up "vector subscript out of range" and i have no idea why. Any help would be great.

main function

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "character.h"
#include "monster.h"
#include "player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<monster*> monVec;
vector<int> monx;
vector<int> mony;
player player1;
bool collision();
void initialise();

int main(){

initialise();
player1.moveChar(3, 6);
bool temp;
temp = collision();

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

initialize function

```
void initialize()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
    {

        int inx = rand() % 9;
        int iny = rand() % 9;

        if (n == 0){
            monx.push_back(inx);
            mony.push_back(iny);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
   -------->if (inx != monx[i] && iny != mony[i]){
                monx.push_back(inx);
                mony.push_back(iny);
            }
            else n--;
        }

        monVec.push_back(new monster());
        monVec[n]->moveChar(inx, iny);

        cout << endl << inx << ", " << iny << endl;
    }
}
```

cout is just to check if its working once it runs and arrow indicates problem line.
thanks

Comment: How do you know monx and mony have 10 elements? It looks like there's only 1 push_back for each one before that loop

Comment: You are accessing non-existing vector element.

Comment: because initially there are 10 monsters spawned and then after that more are added after N amount of turns.

Comment: ProXicT could you elaborate?

Comment: Did you mean to run these for loops sequentially, instead of nesting them?

Comment: `n = 0` is always false.  You meant `n == 0`.

Comment: sorry i missed that. but doesnt solve the problem. but yes it is deliberately sequential because i have to check the positioning of every other monster

Comment: @anon This code is hopelessly flawed in many ways it seems. I see no value for any future research hitting this question. You should inspect your program stepping through with the debugger, to find the causes for these kind of erroneous behavior.

Comment: @anon Even worse, you made your question a moving target now by editing. As mentioned use the debugger please instead of asking on Stack Overflow. This site isn't meant as your personal help-desk, but to build a repository of Q&A that will provide valuable contents for future researchers. If you look at your question from this point of view, be honest would you find this useful if you search for _subscript out of range_?

Comment: @anon Nevertheless don't forget to mark the question, which solved your problem, as accepted, if there is any. :-)

Comment: fair enough i may not have worded the question in the best way. but no one has actually tried to tackle the actual question which is why the vector is going out of range even though according to my lecturer the vector should be working fine. also if there is a reason that this is happening then im sure someone else will encounter the same problem . I could not find any help online hence why i asked on here in the hopes that i could get some help but also so that if anyone else is in my position they could now possibly get help.

Comment: also in regards to being hopelessly flawed it may not be perfect for sure but it is a work in progress that will continue to change and get better as i start to understand this a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

In your `initialize`
you do the following

```
<for 10 times>
    <when first time, add one item to the x,y vectors>
    <access the up to 10nth element of the x,y vectors> //But vectors are only guaranteed to have at least one element each
    <maybe add one item to the x,y vectors>
```

Problem is already that there is a path where there are not enough elements in your vectors. Plus the mistake about assignment and comparison in your `if` like @Michael Waltz already mentioned.

Comment: i see what your saying i have swapped the (i < 10) to (i < n). it now runs but is giving me 12 monsters.

Comment: Try to minimize the count of the loops and organize your code in smaller steps. Do this by moving more code to functions/methods (like `bool check_monster_present(...)`.
Also make sure your assumptions about your code are right, by also checking, assumed stuff with `asserts`.
Also use `std::vector::at` instead of the subscript/`[]` operator, when not sure that the element exists.

Comment: Thanks im just gonna play around with the debug from here

Answer (score 0):

```
void initialize()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
    {

        int inx = rand() % 9;
        int iny = rand() % 9;

        if (n = 0){ //<<--------------------------- replace (n = 0) by (n == 0)
            monx.push_back(inx);
            mony.push_back(iny);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // <<<< here monx and mony may contain only
            //      one element so monx[1] and mony[1] are invalid

            if (inx != monx[i] && iny != mony[i]){
                monx.push_back(inx);
                mony.push_back(iny);
            }
            else n--;
        }

        monVec.push_back(new monster());
        monVec[n]->moveChar(inx, iny);

        cout << endl << inx << ", " << iny << endl;
    }
}
```